# In what folder should a minecraft server conventionally be installed?

Tags: linux, minecraft, administration

This is a question about Linux systems conventions.

I want to set up a minecraft server on my Linux server, and it got me wondering, in what folder should I install it? And more generally where should I place servers I need to manually install?

Should it go in `/var`, I've seen a few peoples do this but isn't that folder reserved for files that might be changed by programs during runtime?

`/opt` seems like the best candidate, I understand that servers are normal programs, but to me it feels like `/opt` is not made for programs that need to run h24. Am I wrong?

Or should it reside in its own `/home/mcserver` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was installed as part of the distribution package, it would use`/usr/bin/program` (binaries) `/usr/share/program/` (system-independent files), `/var/lib/program/` (files that will need to be changed by the program)

If you were installing it directly, it could go on `/usr/local/`. But for a folder containing the whole package, the reight place would be to use `/opt/program`

See the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard for more details on these conventions https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html

Comment: thanks for your answer, that's a lot of reading, I've been delaying reading the doc, but I guess I can't really escape it anymore if I want to become a better Linux user ^^

Comment: They are mostly important for people packaging programs, @Balocre. On your own machine you could install it anywhere, or even use a completely different convention, and it should still work.